# Xcode 11.3.1 does not embed binary third party frameworks to the bundle (IPA)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode11.3

Xcode 11.3.1 does not embed binary third-party frameworks to the bundle (IPA).

I use almofire which installed through pods and when I run the project on a real device the app crashes with this message :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E7080212-1CE9-45FE-A384-738DA0DF6567/testFramworks.app/testFramworks
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E7080212-1CE9-45FE-A384-738DA0DF6567/testFramworks.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E7080212-1CE9-45FE-A384-738DA0DF6567/testFramworks.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire'
```

I assume that Xcode does not embed binary third-party frameworks also I checked the section of frameworks, libraries, and embedded Content and found that the framework is there.

I tried a lot of ways to make such as adding the framework manually by downloading it and adds
it to the framework section but the same error came up.

also, I tried another library the same thing.
It was working in Xcode 10, I don't know why it doesn't in Xcode 11.3.1

Answer (score 0):

for whom using pods:
The solution is to remove the use_frameworks! in your Podfile and replace it with use_modular_headers!

e.g.

```
target 'your_project_name' do
    use_modular_headers!
    pod 'RealmSwift'
end
```